# Show user email when posting comments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when the user creates a post is displayed email user not whose post, and those who are logged in.For example: user(1) log in for anna@gmail.com, added post, log out.user(2) log in for maria@gmail.com and seeing post from anna@gmail.com but this post display email from maria@gmail.com, it is wrong.

**The controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.name = current_user
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

**The view**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %></br></br>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.content %></td>
       <%= @post.user.email %>
  </tr></br></br>
        <% end %>
```

how fix?
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop you need to use `post` to reference the current post instance, not `@post`. Change

```
<%= @post.user.email %>
```

to

```
<%= post.user.email %>
```

Your code also contains several HTML errors (such as elements without a `td` and `br` inside a table...), you may want to review an HTML guide.